# Flask form validation error prompt message

Tags: python, flask

I made a form to reset password, when I submit the form with an empty password, the error prompt words I set in `views.py` didn't show up at the `<span>` I left in a HTML, a default `Fill out this field` showed instead.[image]

*fisrt one is old password, second one is new password
In forms.py:

```
class PwdForm(FlaskForm):
    old_pwd = PasswordField(
        label="OldPassword",
        validators=[
            DataRequired("Please input old password")
        ]
    )
    submit = SubmitField(
        "Confirm"
    )
```

In views.py:

```
@admin.route("/pwd_reset/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@admin_login_req
def pwd_reset():
    form = PwdForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        data = form.data
        admin = Admin.query.filter_by(name=session["admin"]).first()
        from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
        admin.pwd = generate_password_hash(data["new_pwd"])
        db.session.add(admin)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("ok, now use your new password to login", "ok")
        redirect(url_for("admin.logout"))
    return render_template("admin/pwd_reset.html", form=form)
```

In html:

```
<label for="input_pwd">{{ form.old_pwd.label }}</label>
{{ form.old_pwd }}
{% for err in form.old_pwd.errors %}
<span style="color: #ff4f1f">{{ err }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

How to make my own prompt message show up

Comment: your question is not clear, do you want the message `Please input old password` show up in your form when the user doesn't supply the old password or what is the issue exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean how do you get your flash message to display?  Use the following code in your base template page or in each page.  See: [Message Flashing](https://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/flashing/)

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class="flashes">
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```